# How to implement .group() Regex in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have a String :

```
<E-25-Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text-34>
```

I want to get the string "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text" and assign it to a variable "msg" so that I can use it else where.

Here is my code :

```
    String pattern = "([A-Za-z_ ])\\w+";
    //Create a Pattern object
    Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

    //Matcher Object
    Matcher m = r.matcher(frame);
    String msg = new String();

    if (m.find( )){
        msg = m.group(0);
    }

System.out.println(msg);
```

System.out.println(msg) on prints out the "Lorem", instead it is meant to print "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text".

Answer (score 3):

You just need to apply a `+` quantifier to `[A-Za-z_ ]` character class to match 1 or more occurrences:

```
([A-Za-z_ ]+)\w+
           ^
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wB2cX7/1)

Depending on whether you need to capture the first letter or not, you can also consider using

```
([A-Za-z_ ])\w+(?:\s+\w+)*
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wB2cX7/2)

Comment: Just do not forget to use double backslashes when using these regexps in Java code.

Comment: Does it work for you? Please consider accepting the answer if it does.